# I can not to put a text when the editText has android:enabled="false" and android:focusable="false" attributes

Tags: android

I want to have the `android:enabled="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` attributes to disable the typing for the `editText`. But also I want to set a text in that. I have the following code but when I rub the code, I can not see the text in the `editText`.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
```

**And the after code:**

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setText("How are you?");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that your textcolor and background color are blending so try to change textcolor or make sure that any other view is not on top of edittext

Answer (score 2):

```
Your code will work fine. This is my working code.
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>

// In MainActivity

private EditText edittext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        edittext.setText("Hi");
    }
```